# Facebook ads + GDPR compliance

Tags: android, privacy, facebook-audience-network

To get [non-personalized ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) from `AdMob` we can use:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
        .build();
```

Is there a similar technique available to get GDPR-compliant Facebook ads for European users?

Comment: Ads are neither GDPR-compliant or not.

Comment: I believe Facebook Audience Network will only serve personalized ads to users who have given their consent inside the Facebook app. This remains to be confirmed by Facebook as their documentation is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

According to this: https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/1673395492911956/
It seems that Facebook delivers only personalized ads to your user. 
The user gives consent when registering to Facebook. If they turn consent off on their device, or not use Facebook for 30 days, they won't be shown ads.

Comment: This is not really an answer. Showing ads is not compliant, unless you have explicit consent. There is no such a thing as GDPR-compliant ads. Non-personalized ads require explicit consent, just like personalized ads.

Answer (score -1):

No. There is no way to show ads from Facebook that do not contravene GDPR or the EPD. The mere act of loading a Facebook script that then goes on to load ads is in itself a contravention, because Facebook no longer has a legal basis on which to process personal data without explicit consent. Facebook will claim otherwise, but their opinion is based on a deliberate misinterpretation of the recent [Schrems II ruling](https://noyb.eu/en/cjeu), and will crumble as soon as it gets to court.

Ads themselves are not a problem, provided they do no tracking or processing of personal data without explicit consent, but unfortunately the entire world of ad tech is absolutely committed to exploiting every last drop of data they can get their hands on.

The only thing that you can do at the moment is to simply go ahead and break the law, because many EU DPAs are so useless at enforcement (particularly the UK) that doing so presents little risk. However, be under no illusion: it is still breaking the law.